# Sping boot many-to-many GET request

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I have many-to-many relationship in my Spring boot app. But when i try to do get response i always get an empty array;
Here are my classes(I have pasted code without constructor, getters and setters but i have them in my code):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProductOrderDetails> productOrderDetails;
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Date shippmentDate;
    private double totalOrderPrice;
    private OrderStatus status;
    private String note1;
    private String note2;

@Entity
@Table
public class Product {
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    private String name;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private String material;
    private double price;
    @Transient
    private int productQuantity;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ProductOrderDetails> productOrderDetailsSet;

@Entity
@IdClass(ProductOrderDetails.class)
public class ProductOrderDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    Order order;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH})
    @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
    Product product;

    private int quantity;
```

Here is my OrderController code:

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Order One(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Order order=repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->new ObjectNotFoundException(id));
      return order;
    }
```

And this is the response that I get:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "customer": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Company",
        "address": "Main Street 1",
        "city": "Bern",
        "state": "Switzerland",
        "zip": 58529,
        "contactPersonName": "John Smith",
        "contactPersonEmail": "test@gmail.com"
    },
    "productOrderDetails": [],
    "shippmentDate": "2020-12-09T23:00:00.000+00:00",
    "totalOrderPrice": 3434.0,
    "status": "WAITING",
    "note1": "note 1",
    "note2": "note 2"
}
```

How do i get an array of productOrderDetails (array of products that are ordered)?
Id prefer if i could use JPA

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of possibilities to do this:

- **Using FetchType.EAGER strategy**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Customer customer;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProductOrderDetails> productOrderDetails;
    @DateTimeFormat
    private Date shippmentDate;
    private double totalOrderPrice;
    private OrderStatus status;
    private String note1;
    private String note2;
}
```

- Using Join fetching in your custom Repository method:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Order o JOIN FETCH o.productOrderDetails")
List<Order> findAllOrders();
```

Comment: Im sorry if i haven't been clear, but i want in my JSON response "productOrderDetails" not to be null/empty array, I want "productOrderDetails" to contain list of ordered products when i do GET request.

Comment: Have you tried any of the approaches?

Comment: Yes, i have tried: 
`@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o left outer join fetch o.productOrderDetails pod left outer join fetch pod.product where o.id=:id")
    Order getOrderById(@Param("id") Long id);`

but i always get "productOrderDetails" to be empty. Im not sure if the classes are the problem

Answer (score 0):

So to anyone who had the same problem as i did,
i had a typo error, in the Order class i should've used:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.DETACH},orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<ProductOrderDetails> productOrderDetails;
```

**instead of mappedBy="product"**.
And if you dont want to have a recursive call when you do a GET request you should add in ProductOrderDetails class @JsonIgnore:

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id")
@JsonIgnore
Order order;
```

The rest of the code stays unchanged.